# Logging Intellitrace?

Tags: .net, intellitrace

Is it possible to generate intellitrace files into a file at the event of an exception being thrown? I have never used intellitrace but wouldn't it be great to debug an error by tracing through an intellitrace file instead of painstakingly going through a log file?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Whenever you run IntelliTrace (via Visual Studio or the standalone collector), the trace file generated can be loaded up in Visual Studio and "debugged", i.e. you get access to a subset of debugger features like callstack and watch windows as you step back in time

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what he means.  He's not talking about using the collector or Visual Studio to generate the log file.  He just wants his code to record it directly, and if nothing happens, throw it away -- but if a major exception happens or some other condition that he detects, he wants to dump it to his log file -- maybe in the form of "[timestamp] Exception: [exception data]\nIntelliTrace:[IntelliTrace binary file in base64]" -- it would bloat the log file, but who cares, this would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliTrace does not have the means to start logging based on a specific event.  However you can use the IntelliTrace stand alone collector to collect against an web or client application and then open and analyze the IntelliTrace file afterward.  See more information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh398365(v=VS.110).aspx

Comment: What about users who aren't savvy enough to run the IntelliTrace collector? (or who can't be trusted to do it correctly?) -- is there a way to install the collector as a dependency (say, via WiX?) and automate it in the background? (via com-automation, etc?)